# 英語が残っている: 「必要性がなくなりました」という選択肢の説明

Tags: バグ, 完了, 翻訳, 英語

私が[この投稿](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/299676/295232)に書いたように、コメントを通報する理由の内、新しく作られた選択肢「必要性がなくなりました」の説明が英語のままです。

[image]

日本語への翻訳がなされていない場合、翻訳ツール (Transifex) にアクセスできる ja.SO のユーザーが操作する必要があると[回答](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/299679/295232)で教えてもらったので、投稿しています (この回答は ja.SO と似たサイトである ru.SO のアクティブユーザーによるものです)。

---

First of all, sorry for posting this in English.

As I mentioned [here](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/299676/295232), the description for the new 'No longer needed' comment flag is still in English:

[image]

The Japenese translation is missing and according to the [answer](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/299679/295232) (by one of the active users of ru.SO, who are in the same boat as you), it requires an action from someone here with access to the localization tools (Transifex).

Comment: Hmm, this string seems [already translated in Transifex](https://www.transifex.com/stack-exchange/stack-overflow-ja/translate/#ja/english/115592692?key=4f8a33906ccf300474596743d6cb868c)... I'm going to ping CM.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

翻訳を更新しました。次回のビルドで適用されます。

The translation has been reviewed and will be applied shortly.